# How to properly setup arrange and group by in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

My data is structured as follows:

```
Athletes = c("Gus", "Hudson", "Bobby", "Tom")
set.seed(400)
RawData <- data.frame(Name = rep((Athletes), each = 400),
                                Quarter = as.numeric(rep(1:4, each = 100)),
                                Sample = as.numeric(rep(1:100, each = 1)),
                                X = runif(400, 26, 30), 
                                Y = runif(400, 12, 16))
```

I wish to calculate displacement, of each X and Y pair, for each `Athlete` over each `Sample` per `Quarter`. To do so, I have setup the following code:

```
DistanceOutput <- RawData %>%
  arrange(Name, Sample, Quarter) %>%
  group_by(Name, Quarter) %>%
  mutate( lagX = lag(X, order_by=Sample), lagY = lag(Y, order_by=Sample)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Distance = dist( matrix( c(X,Y,lagX,lagY),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE) )) %>%
  select(-lagX, -lagY)
```

However, this returns a `data.frame` that is structured as follows:

```
> head(DistanceOutput, n=10)
Source: local data frame [10 x 6]

     Name Quarter Sample        X        Y Distance
   (fctr)   (dbl)  (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)
1   Bobby       1      1 27.82656 13.85830       NA
2   Bobby       2      1 27.37298 15.67940       NA
3   Bobby       3      1 28.74274 12.25703       NA
4   Bobby       4      1 26.63564 13.07924       NA
5   Bobby       1      2 26.32446 12.64722 1.929508
6   Bobby       2      2 26.88957 14.52096       NA
7   Bobby       3      2 27.53932 15.57959 3.533781
8   Bobby       4      2 28.03031 12.70763 1.443328
9   Bobby       1      3 29.68239 13.82739 3.559287
10  Bobby       2      3 29.43869 12.60890 3.186531
```

Instead, I would prefer my data to be setup as follows:

```
> head(DistanceOutput, n=3)
    Source: local data frame [10 x 6]

         Name Quarter Sample        X        Y Distance
       (fctr)   (dbl)  (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)
    1   Bobby       1      1 27.82656 13.85830       NA
    2   Bobby       1      2 26.32446 12.64722 1.929508
    3   Bobby       1      3 29.68239 13.82739 3.559287
```

How did I properly setup the group_by and arrange statements within `dplyr` to properly reflect my desired output?

Thank you.

Comment: Apologies, thank you for notifying me that I hadn't included `set.seed`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is an order problem

```
DistanceOutput %>% 
         arrange(Name, Quarter, Sample) %>%
         head(3)
#   Name Quarter Sample        X        Y Distance
# <fctr>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1  Bobby       1      1 28.40293 15.40195       NA
#2  Bobby       1      2 26.33676 14.32382 2.330544
#3  Bobby       1      3 28.60779 14.67457 2.297951
```

Comment: When I edit the code to reflect your answer, the first athlete has NA for the entire first quarter. `Source: local data frame [5 x 6]

    Name Quarter Sample        X        Y Distance
  (fctr)   (dbl)  (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)
1  Bobby       1      1 26.59989 14.13808       NA
2  Bobby       1      2 26.74157 15.04485       NA
3  Bobby       1      3 28.92326 12.59923       NA
4  Bobby       1      4 27.45838 14.68891       NA
5  Bobby       1      5 29.71846 15.93510       NA`

Comment: You also might want to include `Sample` in the arrange after `Quarter` to ensure the order.

Comment: @user2716568  As the expected output was not changed after the set.seed, it is not clear.

Comment: @toni057 Thank you for the helpful answer and clear instruction, that worked!